# On Jenkins, How can I let anonymous users to see the job status, but not the console output

Tags: jenkins

I tried the Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin, and it works but grants already too much. I want anonymous users to only see the status, not the console output for each build.

Comment: Maybe the Embeddable Build Status Plugin is what you are looking for https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Embeddable+Build+Status+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible short of writing a custom plugin or something along those lines.  Jenkins doesn't distinguish permissions on such a fine-grained level.